# How to bundle Spring Boot Rest service and Angular App in a single war file

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat

Caught up with a situation where I need to deploy a single war file with an Angular application that consumes REST API inside the same war file. I get CORS errors when communicating with the REST API that is there in the same server.

ex Angular app on: localhost:8080/UIApp and REST service on: localhost:8080/RESTService, Internally service URL is correctly used (localhost:8080/RESTService)

How do I correctly configure that after the deployment, angular app using services being inside the same folder which was extracted by the war file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to note here. Even though you bundle up the Angular app inside {your-app}\WEB-INF\classes\static folder just by --prod option, There will be CORS issue because angular app will consider base directory inside the server. So you need to build the application with the below command using CLI:

ng build --base-href=/{your-app}/
This will make sure that the files inside dist folder will serve as they are in {your-app} folder(HTTP://localhost:8080/{your-app}"). Note that you need to have the same name as your war folder gets extracted inside the server.

Now we finally need to add a plugin to the pom file of the Spring Boot app so that it will copy the dist folder contents to \WEB-INF\classes\static folder.

Add the below plugin:

```
  <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-resources</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/../toAngularAppDir</directory >
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Above steps will configure Angular page to load on your {your-app}. But there is another step to stop the REST application trying to find resources when the angular app navigates.

For this we need to add a web configuration like below:

add a package named config (com.youdomain.config) and then add a websecurity configurator:

```
 @Configuration
 public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
            @Override
            protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);

                return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                        : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
            }
        });
    }
}
```